# Proper way to insert a parent node in DOM/PHP?

Tags: php, xml, performance, dom

Let's take an example:

```
<root>
    <child>blabla</child>
    <child>blabla</child>
</root>
```

If I would like to add a "hierarchy" level like that:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>blabla</child>
        <child>blabla</child>
    <parent>
</root>
```

So I would like to know the best way to do this operation regarding the **performance**. Indeed the XML file I use is quite huge!

For information I code in PHP with the DOM extension.

Thank you

Comment: What is the actual problem? Is it too slow now?

Comment: Yes and I wonder what methods to use. DOMNode::appendChild, DOMNode::insertBefore, DOMNode::cloneNode?

Comment: How does your code look like? It would be easier to start from there. Based on experience it seems that appendChild should be the right choice though.